# Solr - most frequent searched words

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm trying to organize a solr search engine. I've already set up the misspelling system and the suggestions.

However I can't seem to find how to retrieve the top 10 most searched words/terms/keywords in solr/lucene. How can I get this? I want to display those on my homepage.

Answer (score 4):

Solr does not provide this kind of feature out of the box. There is the [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent), that provides you with all kind of statistics, but all of those are numeric only.

Depending on how you access solr (directly or via your own app) you could intercept all calls an log the query string. I did this in a recent project where I logged a queries to a database. If you submit all keywords to an other core on your solr server, you can faceting queries on your search terms as described by Hyque

Comment: thank's a lot for your reply... i'll try with the log intercept

Answer (score 3):

You could use a facet for retrieving the Top X words like this:

```
http://yourservergoeshere/solr/select?q=*&wt=xml&indent=true&facet=true&facet.query=*&facet.field=message&facet.limit=10&facet.minCount=1
```

The value of facet.field depends on the field you like to search in. With facet.limit you'll (obviously) limit the amount of results to 10. You'll find the facet results at the end of the results, starting with "facet_counts"

Edit: I really should go to bed earlier. I didn't see the "most searched" in your question. Sorry for that.

Comment: So this is not the answer? What are the "top x words" returned by using this?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Solr does not provide any such capability as of today. There is a desire for this and a JIRA ticket corresponding to it. You can vote for it if you'd like to see it in Solr some day: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10359.

The stats component provides information around statistics, but it's mostly numeric in nature. You could parse server logs and come up with a way to build a Frequently Searched Terms (e.g. pump those logs in SiLK or Kibana for visualization).

If you have the ability to change the front end and add some javascript code to the UI or can intercept the search request and make an async or batch calls to APIs for tracking, you can use [SearchStax Analytics](https://www.searchstax.com/cloud-search-service/search-analytics/) that provides Search Analytics that tracks searches, clicks, cart actions, revenue, etc.